# SQL Query to get total time logged by everyone and also the most time logged and by which Employee

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query I've written which does what I want, but wanted to see whether there was a better way of achieving this.

Basically, the query below pulling the SUM overall on an Issue, and then finds the Author(s) who logged the Most Time on the Issue.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT IssueNum, Summary, Author, SUM(TimeWorked) AS TimeWorked
FROM TableName
GROUP BY IssueNum, Summary, Author
)

SELECT T.IssueNum, T.Summary, T2.Author, T2.TimeWorked AS 
TimeWorkedThisPeriod, SUM(T.TimeWorked) AS TotalTimeWorkedOnTicketThisPeriod
FROM CTE T
    INNER JOIN 
(SELECT DT.* 
FROM CTE DT 
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT IssueNum, MAX(TimeWorked) AS MaxTime 
        FROM CTE 
        GROUP BY IssueNum) DT2 ON DT.IssueNum   = DT2.IssueNum AND DT.TimeWorked = DT2.MaxTime) T2 ON T.IssueNum = T2.IssueNum
GROUP BY T.IssueNum, T.Summary, T2.Author, T2.TimeWorked
ORDER BY SUM(T.TimeWorked) DESC
```

Comment: This isn't really the right site for this sort of thing. SO is about solving clearly qualified problems, not code reviewn or `can this be done better` type questions.

Comment: @DaleBurrell cool story bro.........

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the person that logged the most do something like this in your query:

```
row_number() over (partition by issue_number order by time_logged desc)
```

That function ranks the rows in your table by the time_logged (in descending order) and groups your data by issue number. Then you will know who is ranked #1 by issue number who has logged the most time.

Comment: Hi Jorge, I know how to use row_number for the ranking and that won't do what I want but thanks for the suggestion anyway.